# How to make HTML page steady on all  browsers?

Tags: javascript, html

I need my HTML page to be steady whenever I click a link or a button. What should I do? I have tried one thing which is written below:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showTable();" return false;></a>
```

The above code is not working for all links, it is only working for the first anchor tag. What should I use instead of these?

Comment: Note that you should not (ab)use HTML anchors just for JavaScript elements; you should use a `<button>` or other element. Style it to look like a link if you want, but don't use an anchor. Further, you should not mix JavaScript into your HTML: you should not use the `onclick` attribute. Instead, you should programmatically assign event handlers to HTML elements from JavaScript code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `return false` has to be inside the `onclick` to block the link's default action from executing.

```
<a href="#" onclick="showTable(); return false;"></a>
```